# Missing HTTP_REFERER after redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, redirect, header, http-headers

I am trying to track the url that refered my website. One way is using a custom affiliate url which will do a redirect (302) to my site. I want to track where the users are coming from. However, I realize that after redirection, the HTTP_REFERER fro the header defaults to '/' when I was expecting it to be the url where the user was redirected from. Does the HTTP_REFERER header gets deleted after redirection? If yes, is there a way to store this information.

I am using rails for my website and I am doing request.referer to get the HTTP_REFERER.

Comment: Referers are not guaranteed; they are completely optional and any number of things could be stripping them.

Comment: can you please write this as your answer so I can accept it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referers are not guaranteed; they are completely optional and any number of things could be stripping them.

Comment: is there a list of reasons that can cause this to be stripped?